# Calling custom js function after Knockout grid loads

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, uicomponent, knockoutjs, requirejs

I have a module to modify the Admin Order Grid using Javascript. As far as I can tell it doesn't work because the Knockout JS hasn't loaded when the custom function is called. If I run the function in the console, it works just fine.

All the files are loading as expected, the only thing that seems to be failing is the timing of *when* the function is called when the page loads.

My custom JS file - fancy.js:

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "jquery/ui",
    "domReady!"
    ], function($){
    "use strict";

    return {
        fancyFunction: function () {

            // Fancy code goes here

            });
        }
    }
});
```

The requirejs-config.js file:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            fancy: "Vendor_Module/js/fancy"
        }
    },
    shim: {
        fancy: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

The custom phtml - fancy.phtml:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    requirejs(['fancy', "domReady!"], function(fancy){
        fancy.fancyFunction()
    });
</script>
```

Last but not least, sales_order_index.xml to bring the phtml in:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
            <block class="\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Vendor_Module::fancy.phtml" name="fancy"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

How can I force `fancyFunction()` to wait until the Knockout grid is done loading?

I was looking into placing an `afterRender` into the grid but struggling to work out where the Admin Sales Order Grid html file even lives...

I don't want to use this JS on all grids, only the Admin Sales Order Grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else trying to do this, I simply created a function with a timeout to check for loaded content.